# Calling functions between React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and doing some homework to understand the functionality. I've come across the below situation and unsure how I can overcome it.

Lets assume I have a function defined in my parent component. I want the same function to be triggered in child component when there is change in data / after the same function is triggered in the parent component.

Below is code snippet of my function.

```
update() {
    const { master, sran, scat, fkey, ftax } = this.state;
    const data = master[s.ran][s.cat];
    if () {
        const fdata= data.filter(row => ftax.indexOf(row.tname) === -1 && fkey.indexOf(row.kname) === -1);
    }
};
```

Here the `const fdata` would have a new value each time the user changes some values.

How can I call the same function in child component pass the value of const and execute that function whenever there is a change in data assigned to const `fdata`.

I have tried assigning props by binding the function but that isn't rendering any output. When I check the function details in console I do not see anything displayed in console.

Please guide me where have I done it wrong.

Comment: pass the function to as props to the child component.

Comment: I did try that. But the data of `const` isn't being captured in the child component.

Comment: Have you tried `componentWillReceiveProps` method in your child component?

Comment: Haven't tried that. Do you have any sample code/references which I can refer to?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the function you want to call in the parent component as a prop to the child component(Check this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)).